# Send data from TIBCO Businessworks 5 to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, tibco

I want to know if there is any way to send data from TIBCO Businessworks 5 to Amazon S3. Any pointers or info on how to achieve this will be very helpful.

Thanks
Vignesh.

Comment: BW 6 has Amazone S3 plugin https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-activematrix-businessworks-plug-in-for-amazon-s3-6-2-0. 
I don't know about any plugins for for BW5 but you can use amazon sdk (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3.html) and implement java code in bw5 tibco project to connect to Amazone S3 and upload/delete/download objects.

Answer (score 1):

you can include amazon s3 sdk jar direcrtly to bw and use it
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/s3

or create a java api that use amazon s3 sdk and fits exactly with your need, after that include it in tibco bw and use it